# heroku limit with django analyzing files without model?

Tags: django, heroku

i created an app using django and heroku to upload pdf files and get some specific data out of them. After deploying I found few things.

1: There is a limit in the http response which i believe is around 30 to 40 secs, however some of these files are super big and it may require a bit more time. Is there a way to increase the time response? if not, any other server you may recommend?

2: Because I am not using a db to storage the files, cannot find anywhere is django or heroku has a limit for handling files without saving them in a db. any specific limits?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your application should process request in 30 sec. There no way to increase that limit on Heroku. For the long-running tasks, you may need to use task/job queue (for ex. Celery).
2. Heroku does not keep files saved on the filesystem, so you may need to consider using external storage (for ex. Amazon S3).